# Why isn't 'list' a reserved word in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just got bit by a bug that would have been prevented if `list` were a reserved word in Python. (Dumbery on my part, to be sure.)

So why isn't list (or dict or float or any of the types) a reserved word? It seems easier to add an interpreter error than to try and remember a rule.

(I also know Eclipse/PyDev has a setting that will remind you of this rule, which can be useful.)

Comment: Suppose `list` were a reserved word. Then how would you change what type it referred to, if you *wanted* to do so?

Comment: If you're worried about these kinds of errors, use [`pylint`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint), [`pyflakes`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes), etc. For example, `pylint` will give you `"W:  3, 0: Redefining built-in 'list'`.

Comment: @kindall: is that a common use-case for a built in type?

Comment: Common? Not at all. But why *shouldn't* you be able to redefine built-ins?

Comment: @kindall: Readability? Maybe it's my inexperience, but how many more lines of code would defining `_list` or `_dict` cost you in such a case? If there's a rule or convention that says "Try not to do this ever", it seems to me that's a sign that you should make it hard to do in general.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Only [keywords](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) are reserved.

`list` is not a keyword but a built-in type, as are `str`, `set`, `dict`, `unicode`, `int`, `float`, etc.

There is no point in reserving each and every possible built-in type; python is a dynamic language and if you want to replace the built-in types with a local name that shadows it, you should be able to.

Think of `list` and the other types as a pre-imported library of object types; you wouldn't expect `defaultdict` from `collections` to be reserved either?

Use a [static code analyzer](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/pythonmagazine/completely-different/2008-03-linters/index.html) to catch errors like these; most IDEs let you integrate one with ease.

Comment: This has been brought up on the mailing lists about once/year, with people suggesting that it should at least be a warning, if not an error. The first time, the consensus was, "This shouldn't be in the language, but someone should build a good linter." Every time since then, it's been "People have built good linters that already take care of this, so use it." If anyone has links to any of those threads to give the rationale, it might be helpful.

Comment: @abarnert: all I can find is a discussion on allowing keywords as identifiers for IronPython from 2000..

Comment: Yeah, I searched for it myself before posting that, and couldn't find anything easier. But I know I've seen it come up repeatedly, in forms ranging from "`None` should be a keyword" to "everything in builtins should be a keyword", sometimes citing interpreter optimization opportunities instead of error checking… Oh well, I think the answer is already good enough as it is.

Comment: @abarnert: hehe, found an entertaining thread where someone suggested `None` should signal a class method (`def somemethod(None, arg1, arg2):`). Glad we got descriptors instead!

Comment: If you're digging up embarrassingly stupid threads from around 2000, I'm going to stop making comments so you don't start guessing which bad, fortunately-rejected suggestions were mine…

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

`list` is simply a type and is not reserved (neither is `int`, `float`, `dict`, `str`... you get the point).

Answer (score 0):

Probably for the same reason for which classes dont have private attributes. This is spirit of Python.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an opinion question, but here's my 2c.

It's a big deal to make a keyword reserved, as essentially it means you can never use that keyword in code, so it's often considered good programming language design to keep the list short. (perl doesn't, but then perl has a completely different philosophy to most other programming languages and uses special signs before variables to try to prevent clashes).

Anyway, to see why this is the case, consider forwards compatibility. Imagine the python developers decide that `array` is such a fundamental concept that they want to make it a builtin (not inconceivable - this happened with `set` in, um, python 2.6?). If builtins were automatically reserved, then anyone who had previously used `array` for something else (even if explicitly imported as a `from superfastlist import array`), or implemented their own (`numpy` have done this), would suddenly find that their code wouldn't work, and they'd be very irate.

(For that matter, consider if `help` was made a reserved word - a zillion libraries, including argparse, use `help` as a keyword argument)

Comment: I'd say that making backwards-compatiblity-breaking decisions isn't without historical precedent for Python. I guess I see the fact that list (or int or dict) aren't reserved words as time bombs--you don't know that you're making a mistake until you spend a lot of time debugging something. I think the tradeoff is that you gain usability, but lose relatively little.