# List comprehensions - extracting values from a dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of names from a dictionary of dictionaries...

```
list = {'1':{'name':'fred'}, '2':{'name':'john'}}

# this code works a-ok
for key, value in list.items():
    names = []
    for key, value in list.items():
        names.append(value['name'])



# and these consecutive comprehensions also work...
keys = [value for key, value in list.items()]


names = [each['name'] for each in keys]
```

but how can the last two be combined?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a name as it is a keyword in python

Comment: The python documentation says that the following are the reserved words...
    `and       del       from      not       while`
    `as        elif      global    or        with`
    `assert    else      if        pass      yield`
    `break     except    import    print`
    `class     exec      in        raise`
    `continue  finally   is        return`
    `def       for       lambda    try`

No mention of list here...

Comment: `import keyword`
`print keyword.kwlist`

still seems to say that "list" is not a keyword. Can you show me a program that demonstrates -any- ill effect from using "list" as a variable name?

Comment: OK bro, I'm completely wrong. Go ahead and use it.

Comment: Might not be a keyword but it's definitely bad form since it's the name of a basic type. `list` is the name of the ctor for the list primitive, `[]`. Or, to rephrase, if you casually did that in an interview it'd definitely count against you as an applicant (assuming your interviewer is halfway competent).

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694559/why-isnt-list-a-reserved-word-in-python  discussion seems to give reasons for why it might be useful. It does seem odd to me that list plays such a large part in the language, yet can be replaced (but then I come from a very diff. history of languages)

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> d = {'1':{'name':'fred'}, '2':{'name':'john'}}
```

You can use the following modification to your list comprehension

```
>>> [value.get('name') for key, value in d.items()]
['john', 'fred']
```

Although in this case, you don't need the `key` for anything so you can just do

```
>>> [value.get('name') for value in d.values()]
['john', 'fred']
```

Answer (score 7):

```
names = [value['name'] for value in list.values()]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
names = [value['name'] for key, value in list.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

`names = [value['name'] for key, value in list.items()]`

Since `value` is defined in the `for` part of the comprehension, you can perform operations on `value` for the item part of the comprehension. As noted above, you can simplify this by using `list.values()` instead.